# Check if a railway track is near location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, openstreetmap, bing-maps

I've been looking into this for quite a bit, but couldn't find a solution. Is there a way to find out whether railway tracks are near a users position?

Comment: Two downvotes? For what reason?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs don't provide a places search like this (see [Google Places supported types](http://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) for this). One possibility would be to download the OpenStreetMap dataset for your region, import it in a database and extract the datasets [Railways](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Railways). Then you could pass the users position to your database (PostGIS) and check if there is a railways matching your filters.

Moreover there is the [OpenRailwayMap](http://www.openrailwaymap.org), if you just need a possibility to do some visual identification of railway tracks. See [OpenRailwayMap API site](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API) for further usage information.

Comment: I was hoping for a more efficient solution, but it might just be the case that there isn't one.. Thanks, mxlse!

Comment: If you would like to work with the next railway stations the situation would be a bit differnt, but for the tracks it's more complex.

Comment: Do you anything about the Open Railway Project? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API

They might have a solution to this, but their REST API is not documented.

Comment: OpenRailwayMap just uses data from OpenStreetMap. Hence you can query OSM directly, for example using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: Thanks, this is it!